# The shortest path between two points on a cuboid on its surface

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I can't find a universal solution to "The Spider and the Fly Problem" (the shortest path between two points on a cuboid on its surface). Everybody solves a one specific case but what when two points can be anywhere?

My idea was to create an algorithm that considers various nets of a cuboid, calculates shortest paths on 2D and then returns the minimum but I have no idea for the algorithm to generate these grids (I guess hardcoding all combinations is not the best way).

Comment: Flatten the structure and use A*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683905/how-to-find-the-shortest-path-between-opposite-vertices-of-a-cube-traveling-on

Answer (score 1):

**Simplistic approach (only works where the points are on the same or adjacent faces)**

Flatten the cube structure to 2d as follows...

1. Start with a face containing one of the two points. If this also contains the other point, you can stop there and the solution is *trivial*.
2. There are only 4 neighbouring faces. If any of them contain the other point, you can place that face adjoining the first, and plot the straight line.
3. Otherwise, then the points are on opposing faces. You need to try placing the final face adjoining each of the 4 neighbouring faces, and choose the shortest of the 4 alternatives. This will not always give the best solution, but it's not far off, and is cheap.

**Generic approach**

Jim Propp's [surface distance conjecture](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/junkyard/antipodes.html) is that *For a centrally symmetric convex compact body, the greatest surface distance between two points is achieved only for pairs which are opposites through the centre.* My conjecture based on that would be that the shortest distance is *approximately* where the plane made by the two points and the centre of the body meets the surface. So you simply need to find where that plane intersects the faces using 3d geometry, and use the faces that are crossed by the shorter of the two alternatives when looking at possible routes. If the plane runs along an edge of the cube (e.g. if the points are on opposite faces and are both between the centre of the face and the corner of the face, and those corners are linked by an edge) then routes through both faces should be considered, although I speculate they will be equivalent lengths.

This solution is more generic, and also satisfies scenarios where the points are on the same face, connected faces and opposite faces.

The only problem with this approach arises where the line between the two points passes through the centre of the body, which by definition means that the two points are exactly opposite each other, because that means the 3 points are in a straight line, so there isn't a plane...

Comment: I think, it only works for cube. In cuboids, if two faces neighbouring, sometimes shortest path can goes through more than two faces.

Comment: After further thought, it won't even work for cubes. However, this triggered a further thought... I will edit my answer.

Comment: Item 3 of the algorithm is wrong! There are cases where you need to pass 2 faces besides the opposite faces. Find an example in this tweet, with proof that all paths passing only 3 faces are longer than the shown in diagram passing 4 faces: https://twitter.com/HermannSW/status/1513281525390921729

Comment: @HermannSW Thanks for the critique of the initial, simplistic proposed algorithm. That initial proposal is followed by a correction which leads to a more generic algorithm. The proposed route for your scenario (0.4,0.1,0) to (0.9,0.6,1) would require each of the 3 edges to be crossed at 0.5 which I *think* is what the generic algorithm gives?

Comment: There are 4 edges in minimal solution as shown in twitter diagram.
Which "generic algorithm" do you mean?
Btw, I am just implemnting Depth search algorithm (not depth first search) on dual graph of cuboid. That will result in <=120 ((6-1)!) different foldings of 1<=f<=6 faces, and for each direct straight line will determine shortest length, and whether line passes only over folded faces. I will implement with modified JavaScript graph library I created: https://hermann-sw.github.io/planar_graph_playground/ I will update here when interactive browser demo will be available

Comment: "You're mistaken: the proposed route on your twitter link diagram only crosses 3 edges: 6-8, 6-2 and 2-1."
OK, you count edge crossings.
But your point 3 is wrong, because it only considers minimum of four 2 edge crossing alternatives, whlle 3 edge crossings as shown in twitter diagram are optimal.

Comment: @HermannSW *"Which "generic algorithm" do you mean?"*, in the answer above, the initial simplistic proposal was followed by a more generic algorithm. I have edited the answer to make it clearer that the initial approach is flawed, but cheap; and clarified my explanation of the generic approach, which I believe will help significantly reduce the number of possible routes that you need to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good question, for which the answer is not at all obvious. In the smooth realm, it is an extraordinarily difficult problem. Geodesics (shortest paths) on a sphere (which is a smooth analog of a cube) are easy to find. Geodesics on a biaxial ellipsoid (an ellipsoid of revolution; one cross section is a circle) are much harder to find. Finding geodesics on a triaxial ellipsoid (a smooth analog of a general cuboid) was a challenging unsolved problem in the first half of the 19th century. [See the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid).

On the other hand, geodesics on cuboid are made from straight line segments so are much simpler. But some of the difficulty of the problem remains.

You may be able to find some literature on the subject if you search for the term "net". A polyhedron cut along some edges so that it can be flattened is often called a "net". I was able to quickly find a site that claims (without proof) that there are just 11 different nets for a cub(oid). But I agree with you that hard coding all the variations is not the best way.

It's not even obvious to me that the approach using nets will work for all polyhedra. I think I see an argument that will work for cuboids, but for general polyhedra, even convex polyhedra, it is not known whether they must have even one net. [See the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron)) I think a satisfying solution to the problem on cuboids should work more generally on polyhedra, and the net idea seems to be insufficiently general, in my view.

What I'm thinking might work is a dynamic programming solution, where you look at the different edges your path can pass through between the initial and final points. There is a hierarchy of edges (those on the starting face; those containing a vertex on the starting face; those on the faces adjacent to the starting face; etc.). For each point on each of those edges you can find the minimum distance to the start point, culminating in the minimum distance from the end point to the start point.

Another way to think about this is to use something akin to the reflection principle, except instead of reflections, we use rotations in space which rotate the polyhedron about one of its edges so that the other face adjacent to the edge becomes coplanar with the starting face. Then we don't have to worry about whether we have a good net or not. You just pick a sequence of edges so that the final point is eventually rotated onto the plane of the initial face. The sequence of edges is finite because any loop is not part of a minimal path. I'll think about how I might be able to communicate this idea better.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for cubes and cuboids by discretizing the cube edges, generating a big graph and solving graph shortest path problem. You can specify start point (sx, sy, 0), and algorithm will determine all shortest path to target points on top face (z = 1), here for 19 * 19 target points. Cube edges are divided into 100 parts. Graph with these settings has n=1558 vertices and m=464000(!) edges, inner loop of `floyd_warshall_path()` for updating shortest path distances is executed n³ = 3,781,833,112 times (takes less than 1 minute on Raspberry Pi400). Orange shortest paths flow through 3 cuboid faces, blue ones through 4. Algorithm generates OpenSCAD file as output. Details in this posting, all code in [GitHub repo](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2038730#p2038730).

[image: image1]

P.S:
I made experiments with 1 x 1 x 3 cuboid and was able to find examples where shortest path between two points needs to pass 5 faces. Code is submitted to GitHub repo, and details are in this [forum posting](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2039210#p2039210).

Orange shortest paths are passing 3 faces, blue are passing 4 faces, and the new yellow shortest paths pass 5 faces! With "mirror" at bottom, allowing to see the bottom face with start point as well. This time cuboid edges are divided into 150 parts (149 inner vertices), and there are 49 * 49 top face target points for single start point on bottom face:
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

I implemented cuboid shortest paths completely different this time, no graph, and geometric distance calculations in 28 possible foldings of cuboid into plane, details in this new forum thread:
[Efficient cuboid surface shortest path problem application](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=340541)

The much increased efficiency with all the sliders allows to change x/y coordinate of bottom face point, number of divisions in X/Y direction and which folding to display, with instantaneous display after any change. This allows to play with a cuboid and "see" how the shortest paths change (on top face as well as on side and bottom faces).

Scale to 50% size, 0.5fps animation shows the 6 foldings containing any shortest path. The animation corresponds to clockwise traversal of OpenSCAD 3D top face [shown on the right](https://hermann-sw.github.io/cuboid_shortest_paths/?s=18&x=0.2&y=0.725&n=40&Y=2&Z=3).
[image: animation showing 6 foldings containing shortest paths]

With added top and [bottom face view](https://hermann-sw.github.io/cuboid_shortest_paths/?s=25&x=0.2&y=0.725&n=24&Y=2&Z=3&L=500).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

but for anyone still interested, this question was solved on stackxechange by "Intelligenti pauca" (with some nice diagrams): here is the original link
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023721/finding-the-shortest-path-between-two-points-on-the-surface-of-a-cube

The "Simplistic approach" from "Richardissimo" was on the right track, you just need to check a few more cases.

Intelligenti pauca:

> If the two points belong to adjacent faces, you have to check three
> different possible unfoldings to find the shortest path. In diagram
> below I represented the first point (red) and the second point (black)
> in three possible relative positions: middle position occurs when the
> path goes through the common edge, in the other cases the path
> traverses one of the faces adjacent to both faces. The other possible
> positions are clearly longer than these.
> [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMV3t.png)
>
> If the two points belong to opposite faces, then 12 different possible
> positions have to be checked: see diagram below.
> [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKmC9.png)

After mapping the points like this you can calculate the distances like normal on a plane an have min(possible distances) as your shortest path-length.